# Run python file in cpanel terminal after closing terminal

Tags: python-3.x, linux, terminal, cpanel, host

I have a `cpanel` host and I want to run my Python script even if close or logout from `cpanel`.

My Python script has get different inputs in at the beginning of the run.

So far I've tried `nohup` and `screen`, but they neither fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been using screen from long and i'm able to run my script even if i close my terminal without terminating process unless until you power off your machine your screen will be running in the background. and you can see the status of your script execution using "screen -r"

Comment: ok if i want to save logs what should i do with this script?

Comment: try running the command like this
python filename.py | tee -a output.txt or
python filename.py >> output.txt
Here we are copying the terminal output i.e. logs to some file